# Knockout: How to update single field in each of ko.mapping array elements

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-mapping-plugin

I have a large observable array:

```
self.data = ko.mapping.fromJS(bigdata)
```

I need to update a single field of each element in data;

The simpliest solution is

```
self.showAll = function() {
    for(var i = 0; i<self.data().length; i++) {
        self.data()[i].visible(true);
    }
}
```

But it is very slow, because it calls handlers after each update. Recommended to use code like this:

```
var items = ko.observableArray([]);
var underlyingArray = items();
for (var i = 0, j = underlyingArray.length; i < j; i++) {
    // work with underlyingArray
}
self.items.valueHasMutated();
```

But it doesn't work with ko.mapping objects.

Now I'm using code like

```
var data = ko.mapping.toJS(self.data);
for(var i = 0; i<data.length; i++) {
  //
}
ko.mapping.fromJS(data, {}, self.data);
```

I dont like it. Maybe there's something better? Is there a way to suspend all ko handlers?

Answer (score 0):

You can tweak the mapping of the `visible` property to return `true` upon creation:

```
self.data = ko.mapping.fromJS(bigdata,
{
     'visible': { update: function(options) { return true; }}
});
```

See [Documentation](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/plugins-mapping.html)

Comment: Yes, but I need do it not in model constructor. If I call it on existing model it is not faster than my first solution.

Comment: You want to transform the array received from the server so that each `item.visible` property is set to `true`, am i right?

Comment: Yes. I already have items (and they are already displayed in UI), and I need to change each visible property.